# Trying to use the value of one field as the label for another input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, label

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<% @prayers.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.date %> <%= p.time %>
  <%= simple_form_for @prayers do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've got a simple prayers table with date, time and name, all string fields. In the view I want to show the date and time, and have the user enter his name in the box he wants. (This is a signup for a 50-hour prayer vigil). This isn't a nested form, because all the fields are from the same table. The error this throws is: undefined method `to_key' for #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `@prayers` is an array of instances of model `Prayer` and the form is meant for the same object from which you're printing the `date` and `time`.

`simple_form_for` should then refer to `p` instead of `@prayers`. The form is for a single item in the `@prayers` array.

```
<% @prayers.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.date %> <%= p.time %>
  <%= simple_form_for p do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```